# Dynamic build variants for build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I need to support creating dynamic build variants in my SDK so that I can fetch different dependencies depending on the build variant. For example, I would like to create 3 separate variants for `dev`, `test`, `release`, and fetch the appropriate SDK. This is my `build.gradle` so far:

```
def environments = "dev,test,release".split(",")

// This part works fine
android {
  ...
  buildTypes {
    environments.each {env ->
      "$env" {
        minifyEnabled true
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}

dependencies {
  ...
  environments.each {env ->
    // Help! What is the syntax here for using custom build variants?
    "${env}Implementation"("my-sdk:my-sdk-${env}:1.0.0")
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To support creating dynamic build variants in your SDK and fetch different dependencies based on the build variant, you can use the following syntax in your build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  def environments = "dev,test,release".split(",")
  environments.each { env ->
    implementation "my-sdk:my-sdk-${env}:1.0.0"
  }
}
```

This will create three different dependencies for each build variant based on the environments list. The implementation configuration is used for the dependencies that are required by your module during compilation and at runtime

**Edit with product flavors:**

```
def environments = "dev,test,release".split(",")

android {
  ...
  buildTypes {
    // Define your build types here
  }
  productFlavors {
    environments.each { env ->
      "${env}" {
        // Set any custom properties for your build variant here
      }
    }
  }
  ...
}

dependencies {
  ...
  environments.each { env ->
    "${env}Implementation"("my-sdk:my-sdk-${env}:1.0.0")
  }
  ...
}
```

And you can do this too:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  devImplementation("my-sdk:my-sdk-dev:1.0.0")
  testImplementation("my-sdk:my-sdk-test:1.0.0")
  releaseImplementation("my-sdk:my-sdk-release:1.0.0")
  ...
}
```

Comment: So I would end up with something like this effectively. 

```gradle
dependencies {
  implementation "my-sdk:my-sdk-dev:1.0.0"
  implementation "my-sdk:my-sdk-test:1.0.0"
  implementation "my-sdk:my-sdk-release:1.0.0"
}
```

How does gradle know which dependency to use for the build variant I am currently running on? I thought I had to prefix `implementation` keyword with my environment (eg: `testImplementation`)?